# How instanceof will work on an interface

Tags: java, interface, instanceof

`instanceof` can be used to test if an object is a direct or descended instance of a given class. `instanceof` can also be used with interfaces even though interfaces can't be instantiated like classes. Can anyone explain how `instanceof` works?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

First of all, we can store `instances` of classes that implements a particular `interface` in an `interface reference variable` like this.

```
package com.test;

public class Test implements Testable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Testable testable = new Test();

        // OR

        Test test = new Test();

        if (testeable instanceof Testable)
            System.out.println("instanceof succeeded");
        if (test instanceof Testable)
            System.out.println("instanceof succeeded");
    }
}

interface Testable {

}
```

ie, any runtime instance that implements a particular interface will pass the `instanceof` test

**EDIT**

and the output

```
instanceof succeeded
instanceof succeeded
```

@RohitJain

You can create instances of interfaces by using anonymous inner classes like this

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside run");
    }
};
```

and you test the instance is of type interface, using `instanceof` operator like this

```
System.out.println(runnable instanceof Runnable);
```

and the result is 'true'

Comment: You probably meant `instanceof Test` in your if conditions.

Comment: nope.. the question was about using `instanceof` against `interface`. rt ?

Comment: @sunil.. Yeah that is true. But if you check an `instanceof` with an interface, you will always get false result. Since you cannot create an instance of an interface, it's not meaningful to check whether a reference points to an instance of it. I hope you got what I want to say.

Comment: @RohitJain please see my updated post for your queries. it is not true that `instanceof` operator against an interface will give `false` always. please test run my sample

Comment: @sunil.. Ah Sorry. Actually you are right. Damn it, how can I forget that, even when I have implemented it in my recent project. Anyways  +1 for your answer :)

Comment: @RohitJain, don't feel bad. I'm totally with you. I think it is a little counter-intuitive that `instanceof` returns true upon interface implementations. It seems to me that to say an object that implements `Serializable` is an instance of the `Serializable` class is a misnomer. That said, it is important to detect when an Object implements a certain interface, so it comes in handy regardless...

Comment: The instanceof operator is a bit misnamed. If you think of it as meaning "is a" instead of "is an instance of" it makes more sense.

Answer (score 24):

`object instanceof object_interface` will yield `true`.

Answer (score 7):

You do an `instanceof` check of a `reference` against an `instance`, and it checks the type of `instance` that particular `reference` is pointing to.

Now since you can create a reference of an `interface`, which points to an instance of implementing `class` (same concept as, `Super class reference` pointing to `subclass instance`). So, you can do an `instanceof` check on it.

**For e.g :-**

```
public interface MyInterface {
}

class ImplClass implements MyInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInterface obj = new ImplClass();

        System.out.println(obj instanceof ImplClass);   // Will print true.
    }
}
```

Comment: What? Of course `(obj instanceof ImplClass) == true`, obj class IS ImplClass! The question is, `(obj instanceof MyInterface) == true`? I guess it's a typo. The explanation is a bit confusing btw.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class Programmers {

    public static boolean hasReallife(Programmer programmer) {
        return programmer instanceof Reallife; ══════════════════╗
    }                                                            ║
                                                                 ║
}                                                                ║
                                                                 ▼
public class ReallifeProgrammer extends Programmer implements Reallife {

    public ReallifeProgrammer() {
        diseases.get("Obesity").heal();
        diseases.get("Perfectionism").heal();
        diseases.get("Agoraphobia").heal();
    }

    @Override
    public void goOut() {
        house.getPC().shutDown();
        wife.argue();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSports() {
        goOut();
        BigWideWorld.getGym("McFit").visit();
    }

    @Override
    public void meetFriends() {
        goOut();
        BigWideWorld.searchFriend().meet();
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice ascii art!

Answer (score 3):

**-** First of all instanceof is used to compare whether the Object Reference Variable holding the object is of certain type or not.

**Eg:**

```
public void getObj(Animal a){       // a is an Object Reference Variable of type Animal

    if(a instanceof Dog){


       }

}
```

**-** In the case of `interface`, the `class` which **implements** it can be used with `instanceof`.

**Eg:**

```
public interface Brush{

  public void paint();
}

public class Strokes implements Brush{

       public void paint(){

          System.out.println("I am painting");

    }


}

public class Test{


  public static void main(String[] args){

          Brush b = new Strokes();

         if(b instanceof Strokes){


           b.paint();
       }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

hi The below will yield True for the instanceOf:

```
•   If S is an ordinary (nonarray) class, then:
    •   If T is a class type, then S must be the same class as T, or S must be a subclass of T;
    •   If T is an interface type, then S must implement interface T.
•   If S is an interface type, then:
    •   If T is a class type, then T must be Object.
    •   If T is an interface type, then T must be the same interface as S or a superinterface of S.
•   If S is a class representing the array type SC[], that is, an array of components of type SC, then:
    •   If T is a class type, then T must be Object.
    •   If T is an interface type, then T must be one of the interfaces implemented by arrays (JLS §4.10.3).
•   If T is an array type TC[], that is, an array of components of type TC, then one of the following must be true:
         - TC and SC are the same primitive type. 
         - TC and SC are reference types, and type SC can be cast to TC by these run-time rules
```

Please go to this link to have clear idea:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.instanceof

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very very old question with many good answers. I just want to point out the easiest (at least it is easiest to me) way to understand this operator.

If `o instanceof t` returns `true`, then
`t castedObj = (t) o;` will not throw `ClassCastException`, and `castedObj` will not be `null`.

This is important/useful if you want to access fields or methods from `castedObj` later on - you know that by doing the `instanceof` check, you will never have problems later.

The only downside is that this can be used for types without generics.

Answer (score -1):

The instanceof operator will tell you if the first argument is an object that implements the second argument.  Do not understand why it would matter that you can't directly instantiate the interface.

```
Integer num = 1;
if (num instanceof Number) {
  System.out.println("An integer is a number!");
}
```

That's all you need.

Comment: Your example is missing the point of the question - `Integer` _extends_ (not implements) `Number`.