# Check interface type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
interface IData {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

interface IDemo {
    Events: {
      GetItem: (callback: (data: IData) => void) => void;
    }
}

const item = {
  Events: {
    GetItem: //mock function
  }
}

if (item is of type IDemo)
```

In the above scenario, I have `IDemo` interface that takes in an object of `Events`, which in turn has an object called `GetItem` - a function.

I want to check if `const item` is of type `IDemo`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487765/how-instanceof-will-work-on-an-interface

Comment: Do you want a runtime type check or compile-time type check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript)

Comment: @eddiewould compile time

Comment: Where did "item" originally come from? Ajax response? A non-typescript library? Or is it defined as an object-literal (in which case we _know_ it is of type IDemo)

Comment: from an ajax response

Comment: Maybe the answer here will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442746/check-if-object-correctly-implements-interface/48444302#48444302

Comment: I have made some changes to the original question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Since `item` comes from ajax response, you are looking for some kind of runtime typecheck. TS interfaces are compile time entities, so you need to create your own runtime checks using your own [type guard.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Something like:

```
function isIDemo(item: any): item is IDemo {
    return typeof item.first === 'string' && typeof item.last === 'string';
}
```

Comment: how would i do it if it wasn't an ajax response?

Comment: I have made some changes to the original question. Please have a look.