# Java comparing interface using == operator

Tags: java, software-design

I have a **ViewModel** that retrieves some objects from a database and some other class observes them and puts them in the UI.

To interact with the database I need a bit more of information so I ended up creating two interfaces, one that more generic and the other one that's specifically made to be use with the database

```java
public interface MyObject{
    // Some methods ...
}

public interface MyObjectEntity extends MyObject{

   public int databaseSpecificMethod();

   // Some more of those ...

}
```

Now the **ViewModel** has a list of type `MyObjectEntity` and provides methods to insert a new object or modify an existing one.

Then the class that gets this objects from the ViewModel will get them as `MyObject`, I did this to abstract the fact that those objects come from the database, that way they can potentially come from anywhere.

When the UI class sends one of the objects to the ViewModel it will send it as `MyObject`
but the ViewModel needs to have it as `MyObjectEntity` to store it (In case of **modifying** the object).

A solution I thought of is to compare the given `MyObject` with the list of `MyObjectEntity` and compare them using **==**, since both should actually be the same instance. (Ignore the cost of iterating through the list)

**Is there a reason why this should be considered a bad practice or a reason why this will bring issues in the future ?**

Another solution could be exposing this objects as `MyObjectEntity` and forget about all this, in that case I would like to know if you think that abstraction doesn't really make sense and is not needed. (The only way at the moment to retrieve those objects is from the database)

Comment: Can you use `instanceof` to check if it is a `MyObjectEntity` object or not? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487765/how-instanceof-will-work-on-an-interface

Comment: @Progman Well ... I know `instanceof` is usually a code smell, I would prefer to avoid it. However you make me think that my solution is kind of an implicit `instanceof` but it doesn't really compare the type of objects, just if it's the same instance or not whatever the type is

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the ViewModel and UI classes, how they work with the `MyObject` and `MyObjectEntity` interfaces and what you want to do. Provide some kind of diagram to visualize the access of the different classes and if possible show the source code you have (similar to a [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

> Then the class that gets this objects from the ViewModel will get them as MyObject, I did this to abstract the fact that those objects come from the database, that way they can potentially come from anywhere.

If you really started to design your system in such a way that objects can come from anywhere then you'd better create a common method in `MyObject` interface and then in `MyObjectEntity` override it with a call to `private`  `databaseSpecificMethod()`.

In this case you will utilize polymorphism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) and kind of open-closed principle.

Using common interface and then using `instanceof` to somehow differently process one single subtype of that interface may potentially lead to additional code changes if you end up with something like that

```
if (obj instanceof Interface1) { // you save into database

} else if (obj instaceof Interface2) { // you save into text file 

} else if .....
```